# Peru: Should I have a passport expiring at least 6 months later my arrival?

Tags: passports, peru

My passport is expiring this summer, however I'm planning to travel to Peru in March/April.

Do I need to renew my passport before to leave ? I heard that they admit you only with a passport expiring 6 months later your arrival.

Comment: Even if it isn't strictly required, you can never be sure of what the immigration official will do. Passports nearing the end of their validity are one of the potential triggers for closer scrutiny. Given that the worst case scenario involves ruining your (probably quite expensive) trip, is it really worthwhile to put off the cost of renewing your passport?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 6-month passport validity requirement is country-dependent, and I haven't been able to find that requirement on Peru's embassy and travel websites. Some airlines are also picky about the passport validity time frames.

However, the [US Department of State's website](http://travel.state.gov/passport/faq/faq_1741.html) recommends that you renew your passport at least 9 months before the expiration date, and you are within the 9-month window.

Comment: Also [Peru's Helsinki embassy website](http://www.peruembassy.fi/suomi/peruconsular.html) mentions no such validity requirement. I'd assume the passport only needs to be valid for the duration of the visit.